# Can I plot an Area Chart in Tableau without a date field?

Tags: charts, tableau-api, area-chart

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Project | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project X | 2.4 | 7.4 | 4.1 |
| Project Y | 1.6 | 5.4 | 2.2 |
| Project Z | 0.8 | 3.4 | 1.4 |

Those month fields are sums of hours worked on that project, that month.

I'd like to create a stacked area chart from this data that looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible in Tableau? The current limitation in my dashboard is the absence of a date dimension, even though those "Month 1", "Month 2", etc, fields, which contain the hourly sums, are effectively date dimensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by doing the following:
First, pivot your data in the following way

[image]

Once your data is pivoted, just create your viz
[image]

Comment: Mark this as solved, if it helps you